# Darwin - Use a kernel extension as an UserClient for another kernel extension

Tags: macos, iokit, kernel-extension, darwin

I have been wondering if a kernel extension can be written to act as an UserClient for another Kernel extension. Typically, we use `IOConnect` on the user's side to access `IOUserClient` methods on a kernel extension. But no such method is available in the **Kernel.framework** (I absolutely understand the fact that it is intended to be used this way). But I'm just wondering if the above is possible.

Answer (score 2):

First off, when you call `IOServiceOpen()` in user space, this calls `IOService::newUserClient()` on the service whose handle you passed in. An object of which class is created as a result depends on whether and how the service overrides that method.

There are a 2 main possibilities, which in turn determine how you might be able to override the default behaviour.

1. If the service does *not* override `newUserClient`, or if it calls down to the `IOService::newUserClient()` default implementation in some cases (e.g. if it doesn't know the `type` that was passed in), the user client class is determined by the `IOUserClient` property on the service.
2. If the service *does* override `newUserClient()`, the class of user client(s) is typically hard-coded, otherwise some kext-specific logic will be followed.

**To override the user client class when using the `IOUserClient` property (1):**

- Create a kext containing your user client class implementation, and make sure this is loadable, etc.
- In the Info.plist, create a copy of the original kext's `IOKitPersonality`.

  - Increase the `IOProbeScore` (or add a nonzero `IOProbeScore` if none was present) in your version of it, so your personality takes precedence over the original kext's.
  - Set the `IOUserClient` property to the user client class you want to use.
  - I'm not 100% sure on this, but I think you need to change the `CFBundleIdentifier` of the personality to *your* kext's, and list the other kext under `OSBundleLibraries`. If that doesn't work, try with the original bundle identifier.
  - If the original kext's Info.plist has a value for the `OSBundleReqired` key, make sure you copy that to yours too, *with the same value*.

This can still fail to work if the service specifically contains code to prevent user clients that it doesn't know about.

Note: including the original kext in `OSBundleLibraries` will only work if the original kext's Info.plist contains a `OSBundleCompatibleVersion` value. If it doesn't, you can't add it to your `OSBundleLibraries`, but you may still be able to make it work - if you're only calling `virtual` member functions on the old kext, for example.

Note 2: This will entirely override the old user client class of course. *Any* process creating a user client connection will get your client, not the original one. This may interfere with sandboxed apps.

Note 3: You may need to add a dummy `IOResources`-bound service to keep your kext loaded while there are no user clients, as normally kexts are unloaded if there are no instances of any of their classes active.

**To override the user client class by overriding the `newUserClient()` function (2):**

This works similarly to above, but you actually subclass the original service class and directly override `newUserClient`. This allows you to *add* user clients (e.g. for a different `type` value) rather than *replace* the only existing one. You'll again need to replace the original's IOKitPersonality with a higher-scoring implementation, but this time you're also changing the `IOClass` to your class.

Some further restrictions in this one:

- You'll need (stable) headers for the class you're overriding. If there's no ABI guarantee that the class won't change size in future, you need to tread very, *very* carefully.
- The original kext **must** have `OSBundleCompatibleVersion` set, or you won't be able to link against it - this is needed for upcalling to its constructor, filling out the vtable of your subclass, etc.

**I probably don't need to point this out but: generally be extra careful when doing this, especially when overriding system kexts, you may cause the OS to malfunction if you get it wrong.** I'd only do something like this as a last resort, if whatever I'm ultimately trying to do isn't possible any other way.